# How to include production classes in test jar with Atlassian SDK?

Tags: maven-2, integration-testing, confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I'm developing a Confluence 4.3.7 plugin using Atlassian SDK 4.2.3.
I Need to include production classes (under target/classes) in the integration test jar(${plugin-name}-tests.jar).
 Since I don't declare some of them as Components in **atlassian-plugin.xml** the test jar can't access them at runtime.
How to configure Maven or the SDK to include the production classes in the test jar?
Currently I'm including them using shell scripts and it seems counter intuitive.